# Ms Access vba to open datasheet view of table in another database

Tags: vba, ms-access

This statement will open the datasheet view of the named table in the current database:

```
DoCmd.OpenTable sTablename, acViewNormal
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result for a table in another database?

I have a form where I can select an Access database, then a pulldown menu is populated with all the tables in that database. I want to be able to select a table from that list and open the datasheet view of the selected table both in normal and design views.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in the following way.

1. Create a link table to another database.
2. Open the link table.

```
Private Sub OpenTableInAnotherDatabase()
    Dim sDatabasePath As String
    sDatabasePath = "another_database.accdb"
    
    Dim sTablename As String
    sTablename = "foo"
    
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tbl As TableDef
    
    ' Create link table
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tbl = db.CreateTableDef(sTablename)
    
    tbl.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & sDatabasePath
    tbl.SourceTableName = sTablename
    db.TableDefs.Append tbl

    ' Open link table
    DoCmd.OpenTable sTablename, acViewNormal
End Sub
```

You can delete the created link table with `DeleteObject`.

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "foo"
```

If you intend to open the table in another window, the following code works.

```
' Note this variable is public so that the opened window doesn't disappear when the procedure exits. 
Public app As New Access.Application

Sub OpenAnotherDatabaseTable()
    ' Open another database in a new Access process
    app.Visible = True
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase "another_database.accdb"
    
    Dim sTablename As String
    sTablename = "foo"
    
    app.DoCmd.OpenTable sTablename, acViewNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: @MiguelVelez You should accept the answer. Tick mark it so that visitors can know, this answer solved your problem.