# How to use Ms-Access VBA DoCmd.OpenTable move resulting Datasheet into a Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Please note there is a similar StackOverflow post from 2 years ago, but I tried out its code and generated *Run time error 2486, You can't carry out this action at the present time*.

[[>The big difference from post /62976682/ is I would like to move the resulting datasheet from the DoCmd.Opentable operation into a access form that I created where the user can see the Table and its contents where I have control the form.  BTW, I thought I should referenced said older post as I was using some of its ideas.<]]

[Ms Access vba to open datasheet view of table in another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976682/ms-access-vba-to-open-datasheet-view-of-table-in-another-database)

To test out the idea I created a simple form with 2 buttons with a large subform.  The plan was somehow to copy the resulting data from a DoCmd.Opentable into the large subform; perhaps as some kind object.  I do not want the user to change any data, just to see what data is in the table.

[[>The 1st button with the single vb command worked demonstrating the DoCmd.Opentable is valid. The second button using some of the code idea I took from the older post from 2 years ago producing<]] an error message stating  Run-time error ‘2486’: You can’t carry out this action at the present time.

Simple testing form

[image: Simple testing form]

[image: The code and Error Message]

I wonder if there was a missing VBA Reference?

Received same error in Access-2003, Access-2016, and Access-365 64 bit

`Public Sub Test01_Click() DoCmd.OpenTable "zzz_p1r4c3_TEST", acViewNormal, acReadOnly End Sub`

`Public Sub Test02_Click() Dim MyApp   As Object Set MyApp = CreateObject("Access.Application") MyApp.Visible = False MyApp.DoCmd.OpenTable "zzz_p1r4c3_TEST", acViewNormal, acReadOnly MyApp.Quit Set MyApp = Nothing End Sub`

Comment: I usually open the database then the table if I am using SQL such as in a scrolling window of some kind.  -  I that what you are talking about?  - Thanks.

Comment: @HansUp  I found something that seems that might work.

Comment: @HansUp             DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputTable, _
                ObjectName:="zzz_p1r4c3_TEST", _
                OutputFormat:=acFormatXLS, _
                Outputfile:="C:\zzPayCom\zZ-Test.xls"